# Parsing data messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging with Flutter and Firebase on an iOS device

Tags: ios, push-notification, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I'm not sure how to go about receiving data messages with `FCM` and `Flutter` on `iOS`.

To give you a quick idea of where I stand, I'm able to receive `push notifications` on my `iOS` device. So I've configured everything properly (or so I believe).

So, when the app is in the background, I get a notification in the notifications tray.

When the app is in the foreground, I also receive the message in the onMessage callback.

However, when I try to simulate a data message through an `HTTP` request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and sending the body :

```
{
 "to" : MY_FIREBASE_TOKEN,
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "data" : {
   "firstKey" : "firstValue",
   "secondKey": "secondValue"
   }
}
```

It simply doesn't show up on my onMessage.

I have enabled Push Notifications on my `Xcode` Project Capabilities.

I have also enabled `Remote Notifications` in `Background Modes` in the same `Xcode` Project Capabilities tab.

I'm not sure what part I've missed because I simply cannot receive a data message.

I have also tried to simulate sending a data message to the sample project in the [dart plugin page](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging), but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin README for iOS

> Message is stored by FCM and delivered to app via onMessage when the app is brought back to foreground.

If it don't work you should submit an issue to the github repo https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: I get that, but when the app is already in the foreground and receives a data message via an HTTP request, shouldn't it show up in the onMessage block?

Comment: I guess it is a bug in the plugin or something not implemented sorry :/